# Ansible: unable ping Windows VM, throws SSLError

Tags: windows, ansible, ssl-certificate

Ansible Server: Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3

```
IP: 10.aa.bb.2
```

Windows VM: Windows Server 2016

```
IP: 10.aa.bb.1
```

Used this to ping:

```
ansible windows -m win_ping
```

Throws the error:

```
10.aa.bb.1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.aa.bb.1', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'),))",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I configured the windows vars in /etc/ansible/hosts like this:

```
[windows]
10.aa.bb.1

[windows:vars]
ansible_user=username
ansible_password=password_for_windows
ansible_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_cert_validation=ignore
```

On Windows VM, I set the inbound rules for port 5986, and also run the ConfiguringRemotingForAnsible.ps1 for configuration.The result of `winrm e winrm/config/listener` is:

```
Listener 
Address = *                                                          
Transport = HTTP                                                     
Port = 5985                                                          
Hostname                                                             
Enabled = true                                                       
URLPrefix = wsman                                                    
CertificateThumbprint                                                
ListeningOn = 10.aa.bb.1, 127.0.0.1, ::1                                                                                              
Listener                                                                 
Address = *                                                          
Transport = HTTPS                                                    
Port = 5986                                                          
Hostname = hostname                                             
Enabled = true                                                       
URLPrefix = wsman                                                    
CertificateThumbprint = 036F429259C04211xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxD5     
ListeningOn = 10.aa.bb.1, 127.0.0.1, ::1
```

I don't know if I missed something in the configuration, because If I used the VMs both were created in the Azure, there would be no mistakes about this.

Comment: What method did you use to install ansible on Ubuntu? What's your ansible version? Can you ping the windows machine using the non-ansible `ping` command? (Be sure to allow ICMP ping in windows firewall.) You shouldn't have to create fw rules to allow WinRM-- ConfiguringRemotingForAnsible.ps1 takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your inventory file:

```
[tag_Name_Alican_Windows_Deneme]
[windows:children]
tag_Name_Alican_Windows_Deneme
```

This solved it my similar problem.

Otherwise does the connection without ssl work?